# How to know which mobile os of a product a user has subscribed to using RevenueCat?

Tags: in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I'm having trouble finding out the mobile OS of the item that the user subscribed to. What I'm trying to do is allow only subscription upgrades / downgrades to same os. (not allowed changing monthly subscription from ios to yearly subscription from android)

To explain the current set-up, I have mapped the same ids to one offering.

```
[offering: monthly]
ios: com.blah.products.monthly
android: com.blah.products.monthly
```

However, this approach seems to have no way of knowing which os subscription item the user has subscribed to.

response data:

```
{
    "allExpirationDates": {
      "com.blah.products.monthly": "2019-04-25T05:07:02Z",
      "com.blah.products.yearly": "2019-04-25T08:07:02Z"
    },
    "activeEntitlements": [
      "premium"
    ],
    "activeSubscriptions": [
      "com.blah.products.yearly"
    ],
    "expirationsForActiveEntitlements": {
      "premium": "2019-04-25T08:07:02Z"
    },
    "latestExpirationDate": "2019-04-25T08:07:02Z",
    "purchaseDatesForActiveEntitlements": {
      "premium": "2019-04-25T07:07:02Z"
    },
    "allPurchasedProductIdentifiers": [
      "com.blah.products.monthly",
      "com.blah.products.yearly"
    ]
  }
```

To achieve my goal, do I have to change the strategy to mapping different identities to one offering like this?

```
[offering: monthly]
ios: com.something.ios.monthly
android: com.something.android.monthly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS isn't returned in the API or SDK (yet). A workaround could be to change the product IDs in App Store Connect vs Play Billing so you can tell where a user is being billed from by looking at the product ID.

A real fix for this is in the "Planned" stage of the public roadmap, which will include more information in the `GET /subscribers` endpoint: https://trello.com/c/ialNFe86/50-add-additional-subscription-details-to-api